# outlook add-in extensionpoint group position

Tags: outlook-addin

I am developing an add-in to outlook, and it has extension points on the msgComposeCommandSurface and the msgReadCommandSurface.

Are there a way to specify that my custom button group should come before a build-in group in the ribbon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. Your group will appear at the end of existing groups of the ribbon. There are certain limitation on how and where the ribbon controls will appear when developing add-in. To get more information I suggest you refer to the following source: [How do add-in commands appear?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook#how-do-add-in-commands-appear)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was not the answer I was hoping for, but I will mark the question as answered :)

Comment: @MortenS If you have strong business case to position the custom group into specific location of the ribbon, you may open the request to Office team: [officespdev.uservoice.com](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=131778)

Comment: In case someone is interested to vote https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/36361003-extensionpoint-officetab-group-prefered-posi